# Question on Escape Speed derivation

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, potential, escape-velocity

Reading lecture notes, I have some questions on this derivation's assumptions.

-

[image]

- It must gain GMEm/RE in Gravitational Potential Energy (where ME is mass of the earth and RE is radius of the Earth)? If it's sitting at Earth's surface, does it not already have that amount?
- Where is the logic behind delta KE = delta U? Does that mean the change in GPE is DUE to the change in kinetic energy? Even if the kinetic energy is constantly decreasing, and at r = infinity it should have no kinetic nor potential energy?

Comment: What the heck is GMEm/RE GPE?

Comment: Apologies! Edited and clarified.

Comment: Ah.  That is supposed to be a mathematical expression.   I thought it was an undefined acronym.  I recommend reformatting using MathJax.  [Here’s a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143293)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is no. It has minus that energy. It is a convention and it may seem strange but the potential energy is negative.

The potential energy is defined as $$U(r) = -\int \vec{F_G}\cdot d\vec{l}$$ along the path of the stone. The gravitational field is conservative, meaning that the path you follow does not matter.

The reference (by convention) for the potencial is infiniy (this means that you measure the potential going from $\infty$ to $r$). The $\Delta U$ calculated above is the energy required to go from $r$ to $\infty$, so the energy at the point $r$ (coming from $\infty$) is $-\Delta U$ hence for something sitting still at the surface of the Earth its potential energy is $$-\dfrac{GM_Em}{R_E} +0$$

The change in the energy of that system can be written as $\Delta K + \Delta U = \Delta E$ but as the mechanical energy is conserved, $\Delta E = 0$. The consequence of this is that if you want to change your potential energy you will have to "pay" with kinetic energy.

Comment: If gravity were repulsive rather than attractive, then the potential energy > 0.

Comment: In fact. You can easily see that if you imagine you are sitting still and gravity pushes you away. At infinity you would have a certain kinetic energy, meaning that potential energy decreased. 

That happens for the eletric field too when you have two charges with the same sign that repeal each other.